# Show that there is no limit exists for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\sin(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)$

Tags: limits

Question as above is required to use $ε-δ$ definition.
I do assume the limit exists for the function $f(x)=\sin(x-\lfloor(x)\rfloor$) is $L$ when $x$ approaches infinity. Since $f(x)$ is a well-defined function, and $0\leqslant x-\lfloor x \rfloor<1$, indicates that $f(x)$ is bounded at the interval of $[0,\sin1)$. 
I then discuss the cases for: (1) $L<0$; (2) $L>\sin1$, but no idea comes out to show the case for $0\leqslant L \leqslant \sin 1$ by choosing a suitable point $x_0$ and $\delta$ for the case. Any good idea to simplify my method of proving this?

Comment: Suppose $n$ is an integer. What is $f(n)$? What is $f(n+\frac12)$?

Comment: One way you could go is to show that $\sin(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$ is periodic, and that a non-constant periodic function never converges as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Are you supposed to mean $f(n)=f(n+a)$ for $0 \leq a < 1$?

Comment: @WeiLam No, I don't mean that. That's not true. Again: What is $f(n)$? And what is $f(n+\frac12)$?

Comment: $f(n)=\sin (n-\lfloor n \rfloor)=\sin (n-n)= \sin 0 = 0$ and $f(n+\frac{1}{2})=\sin [(n+\frac{1}{2}-\lfloor n+\frac{1}{2} \rfloor)= \sin(n+\frac{1}{2}-n)=\sin \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @TheoBendit I have no any idea to show it is a non-constant periodic function.

Comment: It's periodic because the function $x \mapsto x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is periodic itself, with period $1$. That is, we always have $$x + 1 - \lfloor x + 1 \rfloor = x - \lfloor x \rfloor.$$ It just keeps producing the values between $0$ and $1$ (not including $1$). When you sub this into $\sin$, it continues to produce the values between $0$ and $\sin 1$ (not including $\sin 1$). Try plotting the function to see for yourself.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$ doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565469)

Answer (score 1):

**A beginning:**

We want to show for an arbitrary $L$ that $f(x)$ does not converge to $L$. Since $f$ is not a constant function, there are $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)\ne f(b)$. So $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ cannot both equal $L$, so at least one of them is differs from $L$. Without loss of generality suppose $f(a)\ne L$. Set $\varepsilon = \frac{|f(a)-L|}{2}$ ...

(and remember that $f(a+k)=f(a)$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution and can you guys help me to check if there's a problematic?
Since the function $f$ is a periodic function with period 1, there are some $x_a$ and $x_b$ such that $f(x_a)=a$ and $f(x_b)=b$, where $a\neq b$.
Suppose the function $f$ has a limit of $L$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$. Take $\epsilon=\frac{|a-b|}{4}$, then there exists a positive number $N$ such that
$\forall x>N$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon=\frac{|a-b|}{4}$ holds.
However, plugging $x=x_a$ and $x=x_b$ into the expression of limit above gives $L<\frac{3a+b}{4}$ or $L<-\frac{a-5b}{4}$, together with condition $x_a,x _b>R$ due to periodicity of function $f$, obtaining a contradiction.
Hence, limit of the function $f$ does not exist for $x$ approaches infinity.
I am not pretty sure if my proof is getting in a correct way but it is the best way I could present in this question.

Comment: Any suggestion and comment for my solution?